# Set rendered property for CSS resource from a Theme based on some CSJS condition?

Tags: css, themes, xpages, xpages-ssjs

Is there any way to compute rendered property based on some JavaScript condition?

For Example:

> if document.compactMode == "BackCompat"

All examples I find; use SSJS #{javascript:condition;}

For example:

```
<resource rendered="#{javascript:context.getUserAgent().isIE(0,6)}">
    <content-type>text/css</content-type>
    <href>global.css</href>
</resource>
```

How can it be mixed something like this:

```
<![CDATA[return document.compactMode == "BackCompat"? true: false;]]>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use CSJS to compute something server side. This is conceptual not possible, because the CSJS is executed in the browser and themes are calculated on the server.

What you can do: Execute some CSJS and send the result to the server. On the server you then can process the this data and perform your computation for the theme properties.

F.e. you can open an *landing page*, execute your CSJS and then redirect to the target XPage with some URL parameters or a cookie or... Then you can access the data on server side.

```
<resource rendered='#{javascript:context.getUrlParameter("CSJS") == "1"}'>
   <content-type>text/css</content-type>
   <href>global.css</href>
</resource>
```

If you open the XPage with URL *?CSJS=1*, the *global.css* will be added.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would make more sense to modify your CSS so that a single CSS file handles multiple browsers? For example, see http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer

Comment: Thanks @David I tried that as well, just that in my case is not only based on IE version; I want to load a css file if the Browser is in QuirksMode.